# MP4 Video Not Playing in Chrome 56 or 57 on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, mp4

I have a web application which plays an mp4 video at the beginning. This video is not playing in the latest version (v57) as well as in the previous version (v56) of Chrome in Android devices. The video was playing fine until Chrome v54.

It's an mp4 file. Has Google brought in any restrictions on the mp4 video files? The video plays fine in PC or Mac. The issue is only with Android devices.

Can someone throw some light?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found if the Chrome Data Saver feature is turned on, videos would not appear or play.